# I would like to insert a html from result of pandas into an entire html

Tags: python, html, pandas, email

I hope someone will be able to help me form following issue that I am facing.

I just would like to insert a html from result of pandas into an entire html as below,

```
...
df_add_html=df_add.to_html()
template="""<html>
                  <head></head>
                  <body>
                  Pandas : left-only<br>
                  I want to insert df_add_html here
                  </body>
            </html>"""
part1=MIMEText(template. 'html')
msg.attach(part1)
...
```

The purpose is that I want to merge many results from pandas to a html and I will send a email with the html.

I hope I would get some advice from you.

Thanks.

Comment: `"text {} text".format(df_add_html)` and it will put `df_add_html` in place of `{}`. OR using `f-string` - `f"text {df_add_html} text"`

Comment: BTW: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard `format()`

```
template = "text {} text".format(df_add_html)
```

or `f-string`

```
template =  f"text {df_add_html} text"
```

---

```
template = """<html>
                  <head></head>
                  <body>
                  Pandas : left-only<br>
                  {}
                  </body>
            </html>""".format(df_add_html)
```

or

```
template = f"""<html>
                  <head></head>
                  <body>
                  Pandas : left-only<br>
                  {df_add_html}
                  </body>
            </html>"""
```

---

**BTW:** http://pyformat.info

---

If you need more complex templates (ie. with `for`-loop or `if/else`) then you can use [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) which is used to generate HTML in `Flask` (but you can generate any text file)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I looked a result that I wanted and I have looked for what root cause is.